# Juggling two jobs with different pay

Tags: professionalism, communication, career-development, ethics

I currently have two [zero-hour contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-hour_contract) with different employers and different salaries. Let's say for the sake of simplicity, employer A pays 20$ and employer B pays 30$. The problem is, employer A has lots of stuff for me to do and employer B sometimes has work for me.

How should I handle this situation? I'm currently leaning towards working employer B when possible, if not, I work for employer A. Problem with this approach is that I need to make this clear to employer A and I don't want to line these two employers up against each other or risk my job at employer A.

---

Side-note: *The reason why I don't want to lose employer A isn't (entirely) because of the lack of (possible) income. It is because I feel employer A might offer me more job opportunities in the near future.*

Comment: "I don't want to line these two employers up against each other or risk my job at employer A." You're approaching this from a place of scarcity. I know someone who works for Uber, Lyft, Postmates, TaskRabbit, and Amazon. He'll work at whatever job offers him the most. You should do like him. Whatever you told yourself about pleasing employer A is a lie. Being nice and being always available when called doesn't pay the bills. If they want you to be on-call (or on standby) for the next 3 months, they should at least pay you a small amount to wait around if nothing else.

Comment: And no, neediness and desperation are not attractive qualities to an employer. If anything, you try to give the jobs to the guy who is always busy with other jobs. Experience has taught me that those busy people are usually the ones that get things done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd see a zero hour contract as two sided. The employer intentionally puts themselves into a position where the owe you nothing. That means you owe them nothing in return. You don't owe A any explanation that you are working for B as well. With a zero hour contract, they don't deserve *anything* from you. It is a despicable practice.

I'd go for the job that pays more whenever possible. If there are times where they both want you to work, give A any reasonable excuse that you can think off. If they complain, tell them that if they offered you fixed hours, you would make sure that you are always available within these hours.

Comment: Why the "reasonable excuse" rather than just stating non-availability?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need a reasonable excuse.  You don't need an excuse period.  The contact says it is zero hour.  You can just not work because you feel like it.  I would also consider what kind of opportunities employer A really has to offer if they want to put you on zero-hour contracts.  If they respect your work, and expects more consistent work, it makes no sense to put you on zero-hour contracts AND pay you less than B.